# problems with UITableView and reuseablecells

Tags: swift, didselectrowatindexpath, uitableview

so i am experiencing two problems right now with my (pretty basic) tableview.  i will paste my code below but here is the general gist: i'm making a dictionary app, so each cell contains two labels for the two languages.  if a cell gets tapped, i'd like for: 1. cell height increase, 2. font size increase, 3. text align center, 4. cell background change color.

i've also included code to 'reset' a selected cell if it is selected a second time - this seems to be causing my second problem

the problem is when a cell is selected:

1. those four things happen to cells which are currently offscreen.
2. the program crashes when: i select cell 0, the cell changes which is fine, but when i click on any cell that is offscreen at the time (say cell 10) the program will crash giving me this error:

   *fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*

**code:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

            // reset previous cell but only if selectedRow isn't -1 which is initial value
            if selectedRowIndex != -1{


                let previousCell = convoTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: selectedRowIndex, inSection: 0)) as! PhraseTableViewCell
                previousCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                previousCell.lang2Label.font = UIFont(name: (previousCell.lang2Label?.font?.fontName)!, size: (previousCell.lang2Label?.font?.pointSize)! - 5)
                previousCell.lang2Label.textAlignment = .Right
            }




//make changes to new cell that was pressed upon
            if selectedRowIndex != indexPath.row{
                print("new cell got selected")
                cellSelected = true
                // save the selected index
                self.selectedRowIndex = indexPath.row

                let cell = self.convoTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PhraseTableViewCell
                cell.lang2Label.font = UIFont(name: (cell.lang2Label?.font?.fontName)!, size: (cell.lang2Label?.font?.pointSize)! + 5)
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
                cell.lang2Label.textAlignment = .Center

                // update the height for all the cells
                self.convoTable.beginUpdates()
                self.convoTable.endUpdates()

                cell.lang1Label.frame = CGRectMake(3,0, cell.bounds.width, cell.bounds.height/3)
                cell.lang2Label.frame = CGRectMake(-3,cell.bounds.height/3, cell.bounds.width, cell.bounds.height/3 * 2)



            }

            else {
                print("same cell pressed")
                cellSelected = false
                selectedRowIndex = -1
            }

            self.convoTable.beginUpdates()
            self.convoTable.endUpdates()


    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhraseTableViewCell


        cell.lang1Label.text = items![indexPath.row].eng
        cell.lang2Label.text = items![indexPath.row].prs    
        return cell
    }
```

thank you all very much, this help is much appreciated.

Comment: which row did you get this error ?

Comment: @ChathurangaSilva are you referring to problem 2?  it will happen to any cell that is pressed

Comment: nope i mean which code line shows error ?

Comment: @ChathurangaSilva the exception gets thrown right at the beginning of the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method as it's trying to create the previousCell:

Comment: this line: 

it seems to not be able to find selectedRowIndex 

let previousCell = convoTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: selectedRowIndex, inSection: 0)) as! PhraseTableViewCell

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. Do not try and keep references to cells, as the table view will reuse them for other rows. You need to maintain the state outside the cell. Then cause the previous cell to reload using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

Comment: @michael agreed, thanks for the input, i ended up keeping track with another array

Answer (score 0):

so there is  no real answer to the questions i posed, the best workaround is to just have another array which maintains the states in the cells.  sucks i know but really the best "solution"